# Sort numbers (underscore)

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to fix my last problem and still, I cannot figure out how to solve it. My task was to write a program which sort numbers, but: our tutor gives us some extra points for program dealing with numbers like: 000054667 (in fact 54667) and 345_845 (in fact 345845). The first problem is already solved but I have no idea how to handle with the second one. Hence, my question is: do you have any tips/clue, which might help me? I am also sending my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define NUMBER_CHUNK 13


char* getNumber(FILE* fp) 
{
    int length, c;
    int current=0;
    char *number;

    number=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*NUMBER_CHUNK);
    if(!number)
    {
        printf("Error while alocating memory!\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    length=NUMBER_CHUNK;

    while(!isspace(c=fgetc(fp)) && !feof(fp))
    {
        if(isdigit(c))
        {
            number[current]=c;
            current++;
            if(current>=length) 
            {
                length+=NUMBER_CHUNK;

                if((number=((char*)realloc(number,sizeof(char*)*length)))==NULL)
                {
                    free(number);
                    return NULL;
                }
            }   
        }

        else
        {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    number[current]='\0';
    return number;
}

int compare( const void *str1, const void *str2)
{
    int value;
    char* curr1;
    char* curr2;

    curr1=*(char**)str1;
    curr2=*(char**)str2;

    while(*curr1=='0') curr1++; 
    while(*curr2=='0') curr2++;

    if(strlen(curr1) < strlen(curr2)) return -1;
    if(strlen(curr1) > strlen(curr2)) return 1;

    value=strcmp(curr1, curr2);

    return value;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    FILE* fp;
    char** tab;
    int i=0;
    int lines=0;
    int length=10;

    if(argc!=2)
    {
        printf("Incorrent syntax! Use ./name_of_program input_file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if(!(fp=fopen(argv[1],"r")))
    {
        printf("Could not open the file! Please try again!\n");
        return 2;
    }

    tab = (char**)malloc(length*(sizeof(char*)));

    if(!tab)
    {
        printf("Could not allocate memory! Terminating...\n");
        free(tab);
        return 3;
    }

    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        tab[i]=getNumber(fp);



        if(i>=length) 
            {
                length+=10;

                if((tab=((char**)realloc(tab,sizeof(char*)*length)))==NULL)
                {
                    free(tab);
                    return 5;
                }
            }
        if(tab[i]==NULL)
        {
            printf("Incorrect character in the infile! Terminating\n");
            free(tab);
            return 4;
        }
        if(*tab[i]=='\0')
        {
            free(tab[i]);
            i--;
        }

        i++;
        lines++;
        lines=i;
    }
    printf("\nBEFORE\n");


    for(i=0;i<lines;i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n",tab[i]);
    }

    qsort(tab, lines, sizeof(char*), &compare);

    printf("\nAFTER\n");


    for(i=0;i<lines;i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n",tab[i]);
        free(tab[i]);
    }

    free(tab);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for any help ;)

Comment: When you read each character from the file, you can continue to the next character when you encounter something that is not `isdigit` instead of aborting.

Comment: where is the problem?You Just need to do some initial work on your numbers before calling your above code.I think it is quite easy to remove "_" from numbers and handling for numbers starting with zero's.

Comment: @Algorithmist small misunderstanding, I do not want to remove underscore, I want my program to somehow omit the underscore and after sort display the number in this way 34_234.

Comment: If (not underscore) num = 10* num+ newdigit;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change string accumulation and your compare routine.

String accumulation:

```
if(isdigit(c) || (c == '_'))
```

Compare.  This is a bit lengthy to incorporate ignoring `_` for value ratings.  But it is not limited to numbers that fit in any `int` range.

```
 int compare(const void *str1, const void *str2) {
  const char* curr1 = *(const char**) str1;
  const char* curr2 = *(const char**) str2;
  // Remove leading zeros
  while ((*curr1 == '0') || (*curr1 == '_'))
    curr1++;
  while ((*curr2 == '0') || (*curr2 == '_'))
    curr2++;
  int value = 0;
  size_t len1 = 0;
  size_t len2 = 0;
  while (*curr1 || *curr2) {
    while (*curr1 == '_')
      curr1++;
    while (*curr2 == '_')
      curr2++;
    // If a difference has not been found yet ...
    if (value == 0) {
      value = *curr1 - *curr2;
    }
    if (*curr1) {
      curr1++;
      len1++;
    }
    if (*curr2) {
      curr2++;
      len2++;
    }
  }
  // If significant digits in string1 more than string2 ...
  if (len1 != len2) {
    return (len1 > len2) ? 1 : -1;
  }
  return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just keep parsing the string until you get an underscore, and with parsing also convert each character into the respective number and keep adding it to a new number according to it's place value (In a nutshell i'm speaking of an algorithm to convert string to numbers).
 and if you encounter an underscore, just use

> continue;

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain the string representation for your "numbers" but compare them according to their numerical value, don't compare them as strings inside your `compare` function.

Inside `compare` parse each arguments (`str1` and `str2`) and convert them to numbers skipping leading zeros and underscores. Once you have two numbers (say `num1` and `num2`) just `return num1 - num2`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing a bunch of strings, you would be better off converting the numbers to ints by stripping out any non-digit characters and calling `atoi` on the results. You can store those numbers directly in the array. The `compare` function then becomes much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

chux THX. You're brilliant! I wish I would be as good as you in programming. 
I am sending my whole (fixed, working) source code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define NUMBER_CHUNK 13


char* getNumber(FILE* fp) 
{
    int length;
    int current = 0;
    int c;
    char *number, *number2;

    number = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*NUMBER_CHUNK);
    if(!number)
    {
        printf("Error while allocating memory!\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    length = NUMBER_CHUNK;

    while(!isspace(c = fgetc(fp)) && !feof(fp))
    {
        if(isdigit(c) || c == '_')
        {
            number[current] = c;
            current++;
            if(current >= length) 
            {

                length+=NUMBER_CHUNK;
                number2 = (char*)realloc(number,length*sizeof(char*));
                if(number2 == NULL)
                {
                    free(number2);
                    return NULL;
                }
                else number2 = number;
            }   
        }
        else
        {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    number[current] = '\0';
    return number;
}

int compare(const void *str1, const void *str2)
{
    char* curr1;
    char* curr2;

    curr1=*(char**)str1;
    curr2=*(char**)str2;

    while(*curr1=='0' || *curr1=='_') curr1++; 
    while(*curr2=='0' || *curr2=='_') curr2++;

    int value = 0;
    size_t len1 = 0;
    size_t len2 = 0;

    while(*curr1 || *curr2)
    {
        while(*curr1 == '_')
            curr1++;
        while(*curr2 == '_')
            curr2++;

        if(value == 0)
        {
            value = *curr1 - *curr2;
        }
        if(*curr1)
        {
            curr1++;
            len1++;
        }
        if(*curr2)
        {
            curr2++;
            len2++;
        }
    }

    if(len1 != len2)
    {
        return (len1 > len2) ? 1 : -1;
    }

    return value;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    FILE* fp;
    char** tab;
    int i = 0;
    int lines = 0;
    int length = 10;

    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Incorrent syntax! Use ./name_of_program input_file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if(!(fp = fopen(argv[1],"r")))
    {
        printf("Could not open the file! Please try again!\n");
        return 2;
    }

    tab = (char**)malloc(length*(sizeof(char*)));
    if(!tab)
    {
        printf("Could not allocate memory!\n");
        free(tab);
        return 3;
    }

    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        tab[i] = getNumber(fp);

        if(i >= length) 
            {

                length += 10;
                tab = (char**)realloc(tab,sizeof(char*));
                if(tab == NULL)
                {
                    free(tab);
                    return 5;
                }
            }
        if(tab[i] == NULL)
        {
            printf("Incorrect character in the infile! Terminating\n");
            free(tab);
            return 4;
        }
        if(*tab[i] == '\0')
        {
            free(tab[i]);
            i--;
        }

        i++;
        lines = i;
    }

    printf("\nBEFORE\n");

    for(i = 0 ; i < lines; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", tab[i]);
    }

    qsort(tab, lines, sizeof(char*), compare);

    printf("\nAFTER\n");

    for(i = 0; i < lines; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n",tab[i]);
        free(tab[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    free(tab);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are welcome and welcome to SO.  Be sure to up vote the many useful answers.  BTW: making `char* curr1` (& curr2) a `const` helps detect coding errors where you might have inadvertently wrote *curr1.